# iOS: Understanding how to monitor for regions properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview

I would like my app to show an `MKMapView` with his/her location and a few circular regions on it. The app must warn the user when he/she has stepped into or out of certain regions.

I have figured out that I can show the user on the `MKMapView` simply by saying `mapView.showUsersLocation = YES`, and I'm also aware of the fact that I have to `startMonitoringForRegion`.

Do I ever have to call `startUpdatingLocation` if I'm already monitoring for regions? What about when the app is running in the background? Is the GPS always on or is it optimized to use a less battery-intensive approach (the region equivalent of `startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges`)?

Also, at what point should I start region monitoring, and does it ever stop automatically? Any pointers on how region monitoring can be done optimally would be greatly appreciated.